# Images not displaying after first attempt

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am programming a psychological experiment where participants are playing an online game with six other players and in each round of the game, the active player can either lose or win (Image 1). After each round of the game, participants are asked to report their emotional reaction to the outcome by clicking on a corresponding emoji (Image 2). After this, the game continues. In the first round (or trial), everything works and displays smoothly, but in the second round, the emojis do not display for an unknown reason (Image 3).

IMAGE 1

[image]

IMAGE 2

[image]

IMAGE 3

[image]

This doesn't seem to be an issue of file paths, file names, missing files, or variable declarations, and I am out of ideas as to what might be causing this. Any suggestions would be much appreciated, and I am pasting the most relevant chunks of code below.

Emojis are defined outside of the functions. All of these image files are stored in a local "assets" folder:

```
var emojiImagesSize = calculateAspectRatioFit(527, 504, midDiv.clientWidth / 10, midDiv.clientHeight); // Adjust the size of each image to the available space

var emojiImages = '<div class = "divImages"> <img class = "nineEmotionalReactions" id = "valence1" src = "assets/Valence1.png" width = "' + emojiImagesSize.width + '" height = "' + emojiImagesSize.height + '">\n\
<img class = "nineEmotionalReactions" id = "valence2" src = "assets/Valence2.png" width = "' + emojiImagesSize.width + '" height = "' + emojiImagesSize.height + '" >\n\
<img class = "nineEmotionalReactions" id = "valence3" src = "assets/Valence3.png" width = "' + emojiImagesSize.width + '" height = "' + emojiImagesSize.height + '">\n\
<img class = "nineEmotionalReactions" id = "valence4" src = "assets/Valence4.png" width = "' + emojiImagesSize.width + '" height = "' + emojiImagesSize.height + '">\n\
<img class = "nineEmotionalReactions" id = "valence5" src = "assets/Valence5.png" width = "' + emojiImagesSize.width + '" height = "' + emojiImagesSize.height + '">\n\
<img class = "nineEmotionalReactions" id = "valence6" src = "assets/Valence6.png" width = "' + emojiImagesSize.width + '" height = "' + emojiImagesSize.height + '">\n\
<img class = "nineEmotionalReactions" id = "valence7" src = "assets/Valence7.png" width = "' + emojiImagesSize.width + '" height = "' + emojiImagesSize.height + '">\n\
<img class = "nineEmotionalReactions" id = "valence8" src = "assets/Valence8.png" width = "' + emojiImagesSize.width + '" height = "' + emojiImagesSize.height + '">\n\
<img class = "nineEmotionalReactions" id = "valence9" src = "assets/Valence9.png" width = "' + emojiImagesSize.width + '" height = "' + emojiImagesSize.height + '"></div>';
```

Order of player IDs in the game (also defined as a global variable):

```
var playerOrder = ["trianglePlayer1", "squarePlayer1", "trianglePlayer2", "squarePlayer2", "trianglePlayer3", "squarePlayer3", "trianglePlayer4", "squarePlayer4", "trianglePlayer1"];

var activePlayer = playerOrder[0]; // Starting from the first player
```

Function that triggers the emoji response scale screen:

```
outcomeReactionChoice(activePlayer, 1); // First game trial

function outcomeReactionChoice(player, trialNum){
    
    // Dim screen & hide canvas
    dimScreen(); // Adjusts the opacity of the screen
    hideCanvas(); // Adjusts the visibility of the canvas

    // Create relevant divs
    CreateDiv('sectionTop', 'emotionalReactionsPrompt'); // The HTML file contains five divs - sectionVeryTop, sectionTop, sectionMiddle, sectionBottom, sectionVeryBottom - which are used as parents for other elements.
    CreateDiv('sectionMiddle', 'emotionalReactions');

    // Display prompt
    var emojiReaction = "<p class = 'textInstructions' id = 'emojiPrompt'>How bad/good do you feel because of this player's outcome? <br> <span class = 'markRed'> YOUR REACTION WILL NOT BE SHOWN TO OTHER PLAYERS IN THIS ROUND. </span></p>";

    $('#emotionalReactionsPrompt').html(emojiReaction);

    // Display emojis 
    $('#emotionalReactions').html(emojiImages);

    var nextTrial = trialNum + 1;

    // Move to next player
    var activePlayerIndex = playerOrder.indexOf(player);

    // Start next trial unless the last trial has been reached
    var nextPlayer = playerOrder[activePlayerIndex + 1];

    // What happens when one of the emojis is clicked?
    $('#valence1').click(function() {
        $('#emotionalReactionsPrompt').fadeOut(500);
        $('#emotionalReactions').fadeOut(500);
        $('#gameOutcome').fadeOut(500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            undimScreen(); // Adjusts the opacity of the screen
            reappearCanvas(); // Adjusts the visibility of the canvas
            gameChoice(nextPlayer, nextTrial)}, 600); // Go to the next game round
    });

    $('#valence2').click(function() {
        $('#emotionalReactionsPrompt').fadeOut(500);
        $('#emotionalReactions').fadeOut(500);
        $('#gameOutcome').fadeOut(500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            undimScreen();
            reappearCanvas();
            gameChoice(nextPlayer, nextTrial)}, 600);
    });

    $('#valence3').click(function() {
        $('#emotionalReactionsPrompt').fadeOut(500);
        $('#emotionalReactions').fadeOut(500);
        $('#gameOutcome').fadeOut(500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            undimScreen();
            reappearCanvas();
            gameChoice(nextPlayer, nextTrial)}, 600);
    });

    $('#valence4').click(function() {
        $('#emotionalReactionsPrompt').fadeOut(500);
        $('#emotionalReactions').fadeOut(500);
        $('#gameOutcome').fadeOut(500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            undimScreen();
            reappearCanvas();
            gameChoice(nextPlayer, nextTrial)}, 600);
    });

    $('#valence5').click(function() {
        $('#emotionalReactionsPrompt').fadeOut(500);
        $('#emotionalReactions').fadeOut(500);
        $('#gameOutcome').fadeOut(500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            undimScreen();
            reappearCanvas();
            gameChoice(nextPlayer, nextTrial)}, 600);
    });

    $('#valence6').click(function() {
        $('#emotionalReactionsPrompt').fadeOut(500);
        $('#emotionalReactions').fadeOut(500);
        $('#gameOutcome').fadeOut(500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            undimScreen();
            reappearCanvas();
            gameChoice(nextPlayer, nextTrial)}, 600);
    });

    $('#valence7').click(function() {
        $('#emotionalReactionsPrompt').fadeOut(500);
        $('#emotionalReactions').fadeOut(500);
        $('#gameOutcome').fadeOut(500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            undimScreen();
            reappearCanvas();
            gameChoice(nextPlayer, nextTrial)}, 600);
    });

    $('#valence8').click(function() {
        $('#emotionalReactionsPrompt').fadeOut(500);
        $('#emotionalReactions').fadeOut(500);
        $('#gameOutcome').fadeOut(500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            undimScreen();
            reappearCanvas();
            gameChoice(nextPlayer, nextTrial)}, 600);
    }); 

    $('#valence9').click(function() {
        $('#emotionalReactionsPrompt').fadeOut(500);
        $('#emotionalReactions').fadeOut(500);
        $('#gameOutcome').fadeOut(500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            undimScreen(); 
            reappearCanvas(); 
            gameChoice(nextPlayer, nextTrial)}, 600);
    });
};
```

Note: Variable activePlayer is updated accordingly, the code to do that was cut.

Function CreateDiv():

```
function CreateDiv(ParentID, ChildID) {
    var d = $(document.createElement('div'))
    .attr("id", ChildID);
    var container = document.getElementById(ParentID);
    d.appendTo(container);
};
```

Please let me know if any other information would be useful, the code is too long and intertwined to be posted as a snippet. Thank you!

Comment: without a working snippet that can be tested this will be a guessing game, So i'm guessing the whatever you're using to hide the emojis is still applied from the first run, a class or something

Comment: As suspected, I haven't done much with jQuery but i'm sure anyone who has would've spotted this, the [doc](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) says **`The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.`** You need to remove `display:none` from the images, then agains this is just a guess.

Comment: This was the issue - adding a simple $('#emotionalReactions').show() after the line $('#emotionalReactions').html(emojiImages) did the job! Thank you so much!